# What the heck happened to the list of site moderators?

Tags: support

Many moons ago, /about showed a list of moderators with their appointment/election dates. This seems to be missing now. Has it been moved somewhere else, or did /about eat it?

Comment: Do try to keep up, 007!

Comment: The election information is displayed on the "main" site but as you point out it does not work on the "meta" site.

Comment: @ward [Please ask a new question.](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5697/126632) That confused at least one person...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on "Users" and then click the "moderators" tab.

[image]

Comment: NOTE: The elected date does NOT appear in the meta SF site which is what the original question displayed....BTW

Comment: @mdpc The original question did not reference meta at all.

Comment: I suggest you examine the display capture with this question and compare it to the display capture with your answer.

Comment: @mdpc And I suggest you examine the revision history of the question.