# Should follow-up questions be asked in comments or on their own?

Tags: discussion

I imagine the following can't be too uncommon: someone posts a question, gets an answer, follows it, but then finds themselves with a different problem related to the same bit of code.

Should a follow-up question be asked in a comment ("That solved error X, but now it's giving me error Y") or as their own question?

Answer (score 16):

If the function discussed in the first question was *NOT* resolved, then edit the new issue into that question. If the function *IS* resolved, but you are now having issues with another function of the system then post it as a new question.

Quick examples:

1. You're working on software that won't start, it gives error 0x0F. Through the site you get past that error, but now it's spouting error 0x3C and still doesn't start. That's probably the same issue still, and should be an edit to the original.
2. You're working on a software package. The "input" software isn't starting with error 0x0F. Resolve that issue. Now some other part of the system isn't working with error 0x3C. That's a separate question, be sure the reference the first and explain that the previous problem is resolved.

When in doubt, it's probably a new question, and we have the tools to deal with it if not.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a follow up question, ask it as a new question and reference the original if applicable.